# Parsing an image in android when we receive a relative path from server

Tags: android, json, lazylist

I have the JSON::  **`http://54.218.73.244:7002/`**

```
"restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurantID": 1,
      "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney",
      "restaurantIMAGE": "http://54.218.73.244:7002/CopperChimney.png",
      "restaurantDISTANCE": 5,
      "restaurantTYPE": "Indian",
      "restaurantRATING": 3,
      "restaurantPrice": 20,
      "restaurantTime": "8pm to 11pm"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 2,
      "restaurantNAME": "Aroy",
      "restaurantIMAGE": "http://54.218.73.244:7002/Aroy.png",
      "restaurantDISTANCE": 10,
      "restaurantTYPE": "Thai",
      "restaurantRATING": 4,
      "restaurantPrice": 8,
      "restaurantTime": "10pm to 12pm"
    }
```

---

I have used image loader to load the image in JSON and the classes i have used are listed below

---

**FileCache.java**

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context) {
        // Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(
                    android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "JsonParseTutorialCache");
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url) {
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null)
            return;
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

**ImageLoader.java**

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.temp_img;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Recommended Size 512
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

**JSONfunctions.java**

```
public class JSONfunctions {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jArray;
    }
}
```

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView rank;
        TextView country;
        ImageView flag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
        country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);

        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
        rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));
        country.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.TYPE));
        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);
        // Capture ListView item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Get the position
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("name", resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("type", resultp.get(MainActivity.TYPE));
                // Pass all data flag
                intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

**MemoryCache.java**

```
public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

    // Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10, 1.5f, true));

    // Current allocated size
    private long size = 0;

    // Max memory in bytes
    private long limit = 1000000;

    public MemoryCache() {
        // Use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit) {
        limit = new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to " + limit / 1024. / 1024. + "MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id) {
        try {
            if (!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            return cache.get(id);
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {
            if (cache.containsKey(id))
                size -= getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size += getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size=" + size + " length=" + cache.size());
        if (size > limit) {
            // Least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter = cache.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry = iter.next();
                size -= getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if (size <= limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size " + cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try {
            cache.clear();
            size = 0;
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap == null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

**SingleItemView.java**

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    String name;
    String type;
    String flag;
    String position;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // Get the result of rank
        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        // Get the result of country
        type = i.getStringExtra("type");
        // Get the result of flag
        flag = i.getStringExtra("flag");

        // Locate the TextViews in singleitemview.xml
        TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
        TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);

        // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
        ImageView imgflag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtrank.setText(name);
        txtcountry.setText(type);

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(flag, imgflag);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String NAME = "rank";
    static String TYPE = "country";
    static String FLAG = "flag";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);


        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://54.218.73.244:7002/");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put(MainActivity.NAME, jsonobject.getString("restaurantNAME"));
                    map.put(MainActivity.TYPE, jsonobject.getString("restaurantTYPE"));
                    map.put(MainActivity.FLAG, jsonobject.getString("restaurantIMAGE"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now suppose i have a JSON like below

---

```
"restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurantID": 1,
      "restaurantNAME": "CopperChimney",
      "restaurantIMAGE": "CopperChimney.png",
      "restaurantDISTANCE": 5,
      "restaurantTYPE": "Indian",
      "restaurantRATING": 3,
      "restaurantPrice": 20,
      "restaurantTime": "8pm to 11pm"
    },
    {
      "restaurantID": 2,
      "restaurantNAME": "Aroy",
      "restaurantIMAGE": "Aroy.png",
      "restaurantDISTANCE": 10,
      "restaurantTYPE": "Thai",
      "restaurantRATING": 4,
      "restaurantPrice": 8,
      "restaurantTime": "10pm to 12pm"
    }
```

---

I need to append the below

```
http://54.218.73.244:7002/
```

for **restaurantIMAGE** on the android client part so when I receive the relative path from server i can use it ..... how to perform this process and make changes in code

Any ideas

Hope I am clear

Answer (score 2):

try this, Instead of this

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(flag, imgflag);
```

Use this one it will help you.

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://54.218.73.244:7002/"+flag, imgflag);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the arraylist and append the imagename to the URL. Add  URl="http://54.218.73.244:7002" in your constant class( if you have any )So you dont need to edit the code everywhere if the url changes. And  you can also use
http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/  for automatic image caching